# Understanding a theorem about double series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence, summation

In baby Rudin, there is a theorem stated that:

> Given a double series $\{a_{ij}\},i=1,2,3,...,j=1,2,3,...,$ suppose that $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|a_{ij}|=b_{i}$$
>   and $\sum b_i$ converges. Then
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$$
>   Proof:
>   Let E be a countable set, consisting of the points $x_0,x_1,...,$ and suppose $x_n\to x_0$ as $n \to \infty$. Define 
>   (1)
>   $$f_i(x_0)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$$
>   (2)
>   $$f_i(x_n)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}$$
>   (3)
>   $$g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i(x)$$
>   Now each $f_i$ is continuous at $x_0$ and (3) converges uniformly, so g is continuous at $x_0$. So
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$$
>   $$=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i(x_0)=g(x_0)$$
>   $$=\lim_{n\to \infty} g(x_n)$$
>   $$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i(x_n)$$
>   $$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}$$
>   $$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{ij}$$
>   $$=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{ij}$$

What I don't understand is, why $=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{ij}$
Is it rearrangement of absolute convergent series? But is it really a rearrangement from $a_{11},a_{12},...,a_{1n},a_{21},a_{22},...,a_{2n},...$ to $a_{11},a_{21},a_{31},...(to\,\,infinity),a_{21},a_{22},...,a_{n1},a_{n2},...$? Since there are infinitely many terms berfore a_{21}, how can it be done?

Comment: It's not a rearrangement of anything, it's  just a generalization to $n$ sums, $n>2$, of the fact that if $\sum a_j$ and $\sum b_j$ both converge then $\sum(a_j+b_j)$ converges and $\sum(a_j+b_j)=\sum a_j+\sum b_j$.

Comment: I still can not understand, sorry. Could you give more details?